# Como desabilitar um campo input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Após ter recebido um valor, como bloquear um campo input para que não tenha o seu valor alterado? abaixo há dois campos; como bloquear apenas o campo 'NOME FANTASIA' e manter 'CNPJ' para receber um novo valor?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#pesquisar').on('click', function(e) {
    
   
    e.preventDefault();
    
   
    var cnpj = $('#cnpj').val().replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
    
    
    if(cnpj.length == 14) {
    
     
      $.ajax({
        url:'https://www.receitaws.com.br/v1/cnpj/' + cnpj,
        method:'GET',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        complete: function(xhr){
        
         
          response = xhr.responseJSON;
          
       
          if(response.status == 'OK') {
          
          
            $('#nome').val(response.fantasia);
            ;
          
          } else {
            alert(response.message);
          }
        }
      });
    
   
    } else {
      alert('CNPJ inválido');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formu">
        <p>Cadastro de Empresa</p>
      <fieldset id="first">
    
       <label for="cnpj">CNPJ</label><br/>
        <input id="cnpj" type="text" name="cnpj" size="35" maxlength="14" style="margin-right:20px; " value="27865757000102"><!-- Coloquei o value já preenchido apenas para facilitar os testes durante o desenvolvimento -->
         <input id="pesquisar" type="button" name="pesqui" value="Pesquisar"><!-- Aqui incluímos o id="pesquisar" para poder aplicar o evento pelo ID e mudamos o type para "button"--><br/><br/>
       
       <label for="nome">Nome fantasia</label><br/>
        <input id="nome" type="text" name="nome" size="35" maxlength="50"><br/><br/>
      </fieldset>
        
      <br/><input id=save type="submit" name="salvar" value="Salvar">
     </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Como esse elemento tem ID podes usar simplesmente

```
document.getElementById('nome').disabled = true;
// ou para ficar só de leitura
document.getElementById('nome').readOnly = true;
```

Exemplo:

```js
$('#pesquisar').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById('nome').readOnly = true;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formu">
  <p>Cadastro de Empresa</p>
  <fieldset id="first">

    <label for="cnpj">CNPJ</label><br/>
    <input id="cnpj" type="text" name="cnpj" size="35" maxlength="14" style="margin-right:20px; " value="27865757000102">
    <!-- Coloquei o value já preenchido apenas para facilitar os testes durante o desenvolvimento -->
    <input id="pesquisar" type="button" name="pesqui" value="Pesquisar">
    <!-- Aqui incluímos o id="pesquisar" para poder aplicar o evento pelo ID e mudamos o type para "button"--><br/><br/>

    <label for="nome">Nome fantasia</label><br/>
    <input id="nome" type="text" name="nome" size="35" maxlength="50"><br/><br/>
  </fieldset>

  <br/><input id=save type="submit" name="salvar" value="Salvar">
</form>
```

**Nota:** Campos com disabled e campos com `display: none;` (anteriores ao IE9) não são enviados com o `submit` de form.

Comment: lembrando que `disabled` não passa o valor e `readOnly` passa

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo boa observação. Juntei isso e `display: none;` para o caso de alguém ler isto sem saber esses efeitos "laterais".

Comment: @Sergio Cara, testei aqui um input com `display:none` e enviou normal no submit: `<input type="text" name="teste" value="blabla" style="display:none;" />`. O "blabla" foi normalmente apresar do campo estar oculto.

Comment: @Dvdsamm antigamente isso era um problema conhecido. Estive a pesquisar agora e de facto a partir do IE9 isso já não acontece. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/8318442/2256325)

Answer (score 0):

Para bloquear a alteração no referido `input`, use jQuery para atribuir `readonly` 
(*somente leitura*) ao campo.

**Código:**

```
$('#nome').prop('readonly', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Por
disable="disable" na input
Ex:

> `<input type="text" id="" name="" value="exemplo" disabled="disabled"/>`